# Disable JS Submit Validation Checks

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I don't really know how to explain this one very well so here we go.

I am trying to implement the Stripe payment button on my page. When the submit button is click, the JS validates the users input. That said, I do not have access to the JS file.

I am trying to add the ability for users to choose weather to pay by check (in which the stripe form elements disappear and other appear related to paying by check).The problem is, when the user selects to pay by check and click submit, the validation checks for the stripe form are run, they of corse fail and the submit action is aborted.

So how, when the user selects check, can I disable the Stripe actions?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple different options.  One would be to work with the event handlers in javascript when the user chooses to pay by check.  Another option (probably simpler) option would be to have 2 submit buttons and show and hide them depending on how the user intends to pay.

Answer (score 1):

You should have different forms for the different payment methods, so that the Stripe form doesn't think it is being submitted.

Here's my guess as to how you could disable the listeners, anyway:

```
$("#payment-form").unbind('submit');
```